# Ui is getting distorted when the device is locked and unlocked for few times- objectivec

Tags: ios, ios4

I am not new to objectivec but i am new to the issue i am facing, i have an alert view with two buttons cancel and ok, when the device/simulator is locked and unlocked for few times, the alert ui is getting distorted that means the buttons are moving 2px for each device lock, i have googled lots but i did not get any clue. Can anyone please help me. Thankls in Advance

Comment: when we cant find a solution.. blame apple !!

Comment: Any pictures to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Yes, i am attaching two pictures here, one is the initial one and the other is after locked and unlocked